# Magento : Call an attribute within an email template?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to call a custom attribute called `subtitle` in the template file

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

I have tried

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()->getId())->getdata('subtitle')
```

but no luck so far.  Would anyone be willing to help, I've been trying several things for hours now. :(

Comment: If you created your custom attribute for the `catalog_product` entity, then `->getData('subtitle')` (note the upper 'D' in getData) or `->getSubtitle()` should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! was beginning to think I was on my own.  The error I get using the code I originally posted is as follows 'Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object'. When I say custom attribute, it is one that I created in the magento backend.  So I'm not sure what you mean by 'If you created your custom attribute for the catalog_product entity'

Comment: Just to make sure: you are talking about custom _attributes_ (`Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Add New Attribute`), but not about custom _variables_ (`System -> Custom Variables`), right?

Comment: Yes that is correct Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Add New Attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code assumes that `$this->getProduct()` returns a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` object.

The error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object` tells us, that `$this->getProduct()` actually does *not* return any object (but probably `null` instead).

The template

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

you're talking about, is included by `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Email_Items_Order_Default`, but afaik this block does not have any `getProduct()` method by default.

So either you are missing, that there's no such method, or you've defined your own method and it doesn't return an `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` instance (for whatever reasons).

**EDIT**:

One way to fix this would be to change the first lines of your template from

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
```

to

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
```

After this change, you can use

```
$_product->getSubtitle()
```

to get the value of your custom attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't defined my own method. Would there be any way to get hold of the data I want from within this block?  You'll have to excuse me, I'm still not great with classes and object oriented PHP.

Comment: No worries^^ Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a `var_dump()` or debug the `$_item` variable in the template. I bet you will find some sort of product object somewhere in the `$_item` variable, and you'll most likely be able to find its ID. (Maybe even with something similar to `$productId = $_item->getProduct()->getId()`?) Once you've found the product ID, you can definitely find your attribute via this code

```
// $productId = Whatever product ID was found previously
if ($productId) {
    $subtitle = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getSubtitle();
    if ($subtitle) {
        echo 'This is the subtitle ' . $subtitle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using **multistore** Magento setup and attribute values are different per sore, you could use the following.

First, load the product in email/order/items/order/default.phtml:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($_order->getStoreId())->load($_item->getProductId());
```

To get attribute's "subtitle" value, use this:

```
$_product->getSubtitle();
```

In case you want to get the attribute label:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('subtitle')->getStoreLabel($_order->getStoreId());
```

And if f.e. your attribute is a dropdown type, to get the value use this:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('dropdown_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Tested on Magento CE 1.6.2.0.